# Django: Retrieve list of unique m2m combinations

Tags: python, django

I have the following model schema in Django (Note that I left out a detailed overview of class ModelB as it is irrelevant for the question)

```
class ModelA(Models.model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, blank=True)
```

Given a QuerySet of ModelA objects, I would like to receive all unique M2M combinations (of ModelB objects) that are present in the queryset. For example, for the following queryset of 4 ModelA objects:

```
| id       | b (m2m field)    | 
| -------- | ---------------- | 
| 1        | [1,2,3]          |
| 2        | [1,2]            |
| 3        | [1,2]            |
| 4        | []               |
```

I would like to return a list/queryset that looks like `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[]]`. Is there an elegant way to do this in Django? I have tried to do the following: `

```
queryset.values_list('b',flat=True).distinct()
```

But this returns a flat list of all unique ModelB objects present in the entire table (e.g.: `[1,2,3]`). Hence, I lose the granularity of the combinations in which the ModelB objets occur in the m2m field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers with the same question, I ended up using a combination of [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)  and and [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) like this:

```
unique_combinations = (
    ModelA.objects.annotate(id_list=ArrayAgg("b", ordering="b", distinct=True))
    .values("id_list")
    .distinct()
)
```

I first annotate each object with the `id_list` field, which contains all the sorted and unique ids of the `ModelB` objects in the m2m relation. I then retrieve the `id_list` values from the queryset and only keep the distinct items. The result is a queryset containing all (unique) m2m combinations of `ModelB` objects present in the `ModelA` queryset.

Note that it is important to add the ordering when applying `ArrayAgg` during annotation, as the `.distinct()` operator does not filter out combinations with the same entries but with different ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the through model via `ModelA.b.through`. From there you can query on that model which will have fields to both ModelB and ModelA. The model structure would be something similar to:

```
ThroughModel:
    id: int
    a_id: int
    a: ModelA
    b_id: int
    b: ModelB
```

From there you'd still need to devise the query to fetch the data in the shape that you want. You should be able to achieve it with [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Subquery) and [`ArrayAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.ArrayAgg)